# Preventing bleedthrough of colours on transparent TabNavigator component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I was having a problem rendering text in a `TabNavigator` with a transparent `TabBar`, because I wanted to show the background `Image`.  That image was mostly red, and I wanted pure white text for the labels, but they were coming out pink.  The problem was that RN was blending then background colour with the text colour.  Essentially, RN was not giving the text view 100% opacity.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions for a better title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I added

```
   backgroundColor: '#ffffff00', 
        opacity:100
```

to `tabStyle`in `tabBarOptions`.